# How to populate all the array values to a single index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has values at two indexes and i want to populate the values of two indexes into one index probably in a different array.

```
this.nodesObjResultSingular =  (2) [Array(6), Array(6)]

this.nodesObjResultSingular = [
[
    {sets: Array(1), size: 12},
    {sets: Array(1), size: 12},
    {sets: Array(1), size: 12},
    {sets: Array(2), size: 2},
    {sets: Array(2), size: 2},
    {sets: Array(2), size: 2}
],
[{sets: Array(1), size: 12},
{sets: Array(1), size: 12},
{sets: Array(1), size: 12},
{sets: Array(2), size: 2},
{sets: Array(2), size: 2},
{sets: Array(2), size: 2}]
];
```

How can I get the following ?

```
finalVenn = // all the 12 values of this.nodesObjResultSingular.
```

Comment: Want to combines the two array?

Comment: two is just an example...  populate more than two arrays into one single array

Comment: `const flattened = [].concat(...nodesObjResultSingular )`

Comment: or..... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unknown number if arrays, you can use *reduce* with *concat*:

```js
let data = [
[{sets: Array(1), size: 12},{sets: Array(1), size: 12},{sets: Array(1), size: 12},{sets: Array(2), size: 2},{sets: Array(2), size: 2},{sets: Array(2), size: 2}],
[{sets: Array(1), size: 12},{sets: Array(1), size: 12},{sets: Array(1),size: 12},{sets: Array(2), size: 2},{sets: Array(2), size: 2},{sets: Array(2), size: 2}]];

var merged = data.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), []);
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use spread operator to concat them. like:

```
finalVenn = [...this.nodesObjResultSingular[0], ...this.nodesObjResultSingular[1]]
```

Or could also use `Array.concat()`

```
finalVenn = this.nodesObjResultSingular[0].concat(this.nodesObjResultSingular[1])
```

If you have multiple indeces to concat then use:

```js
var multipleArr = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6 ]]
var res = [].concat.apply([], multipleArr)
console.log(res)
```